# Convergence of integral power of $\cos$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Find the integral and find $k$ in order to converge  ($k$ is real number).
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos (\theta) ^{2k} d\theta.$$

I can find the value of integral if $k$ is integer, but what happens with a real number $k$?

Thank you!

Comment: There is a singularity at $\theta = \pi /2$, for $k \le 0$. While, for $k > 0$, the integrand function is continuous, so the integral is convergent.

Comment: Hint: in the given range, $1-2x/\pi\le\cos(\theta)\le1-(2x/\pi)^2$. The integral of the second function is a Beta integral. Both bounds converge for $\Re(2k)>1$.

Answer (score 1):

For $k$ positive, the integrand remains bounded by $1$.

For $k$ negative, there is a singularity at $\theta=\dfrac\pi2$. As we have $$\cos(\theta)\ge1-\frac{2\theta}\pi$$

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos (\theta) ^{2k} d\theta\le \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left(1-\frac{2\theta}\pi\right) ^{2k} d\theta=\frac1{2k+1}\left(1-\frac{2\theta}\pi\right) ^{2k+1},$$ the given integral converges for $2k>-1$.

And as

$$\cos(\theta)\le\frac\pi2-\theta$$ it diverges for $2k\le-1$.

In simpler terms, the cosine is essentially linear in the neighborhoord of its root, so that the integrand behaves like $x^\alpha$ near $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that $$B(x,y) = 2\int_0^{\pi/2}(\sin\theta)^{2x-1}(\cos\theta)^{2y-1}\,\mathrm{d}\theta, \qquad \Re(x)>0,\ \Re(y)>0 $$
we have
$$
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos (\theta) ^{2k} \,\mathrm d\theta=\frac{1}{2}B\left(\frac{1}{2},k+\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\,\Gamma\left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2\Gamma(k+1)}\qquad\text{for}\;\;k\in\Bbb C\;\text{with}\;\;\Re(k)>-\frac{1}{2}
$$